# Get all custom fields that belong to a certain box in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

How can I get all custom fields that belong to a certain box only.

For example, I am using the "more fields" plugin which allows me to create boxes of custom fields  for instance a box called "hotel features" with different custom fields as the particular features.

Teh point is that when I extract meta data in the template, there is no way, known to me, how to get only the fields that belong to the "hotel features box", say.

Please, help with suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Different plugins use different field values, your best bet is to use firebug (or the like) and inspect the custom field values used in the meta box. Additionally if the fields appear in the custom fields area, you can get their names from there.

I've recently written a few tutorials on creating custom meta boxes, they might help you out:
[Take Your WordPress Meta Box to the Next Level](http://farinspace.com/wordpress-meta-box-next-level/)